# How can I traverse a multi level php object and unset the deepest node dynamically

Tags: php, object, unset

I have an object that is in the form:

```
CommentID: [
  "UserID": UserID, 
  "Status": "active/deleted", 
  "DateTime": "DateTime", 
  "Comment": "CommentText",  
  "Likes": [
    UserID: DateTime of Like, 
    UserID: DateTime of Like...
  ], 
  "Comments": [same as parent]
]
```

This means, I could have multiple levels of comments -> A comment on a comment on a comment.

If I want to delete a comment, I get from the view the full chain of CommentIDs... parent commentID, sub-parent, sub-sub.. etc..

How can I now unset this particular comment.

Something like this:

Imagine I get the following: 1;2;3 where 1 is CommentID of parent, 2 is CommentID of child of parent and 3 is CommentID of child of child.

This comes to me as a variable in PHP.

I would like now to unset  3..

ideally, I'd write,

`unset($object->{1}->{2}->{3});` and it will work.

But, i can't assume the number of levels. So I have to somehow loop through the comment ID's and figure out a way.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly. Is it say a comment on a post and users can comment on those? If so it would be intelligent to create a better and smarter  associative array. And when the user deletes this comment pass it's parents id's through that. So the user deletes their post and it's I'd is 0192473 from parent 01184729 and it's parent is 01937482. So pass a get parameters which would be such as ID: 0192473|01184729|01937482 NOW that's just an idea and if I built the system I am sure I'd write this so it was smoother, more intelligent, and efficient. But that's my take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of what you actually have, I'm assuming you have an array of comments, and inside of each comment could be an array of more comments inside the `comments` field.

If this is the case you would be doing something along the lines of

`unset($object->comments[1]->comments[2]->comments[3]);`

This would unset the third comment, of the second comment of the first comment in your object.

If this is not the answer you are looking for, please give an actually example.

> **Sudo** Recursion example

```
function unsetLowestComment($comment) {
  $commentsLength = count($comment->comments);
  if($commentsLength > 0) {
    unsetLowestComment($comment->comments[$commentsLength -1]);
  } else {
    unset($comment);
  }
}

unsetLowestComment($commentInQuestion);
```

Comment: Exactly how you wrote it. Now, the only problem with unset is you have to hard write the tree .. comments[1]->comments[2] etc.. but if I have 1,2 and 3 coming as a variable .. and I do not know how deep that is.. it could be 1,2,3,4 or 1,2  or 1,2,3,4,5 ... how can I use a for loop of sorts to create the unset function that will eventually unset the last chain

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: Yes, I know what it can do - I just do not know how to get done with unset and a php function :s

Comment: findLowestComment isn't declared anywhere, did you mean, unsetLowestComment

Comment: yes sorry, i changed the name of it half way through

Comment: I'm going to try it now and see if it works. Will mark answer as correct as soon as it works .. :) thanks a tonne.. I was just too scared to attempt recursion it seems.

Comment: No problem. Recursion is a little scarey with the potential of endless loops, but its a life saver when you get it working. Hope i got you started :-)